# cocos2d 3.x prevent screen rotation

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using Cocos2d 3.x and I want the screen orientation to be completely locked.  I am creating an app that uses the accelerometer information to move a sprite in the x and y directions. When I lean the screen forward too far, the screen switches from landscape orientation with the button on the left to landscape orientation with the button on the right.  I never want this to happen; I always want the orientation to remain landscape orientation with the button on the left. I would assume this is easy to do, and it has already been answered, but after searching for quite some time I still can't figure it out. Any suggestions? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: same as for any app, check xcode target settings (there are allowed orientation buttons) or check info.plist

Comment: I've tried about a dozen different approaches in the target settings and info.plist with no luck. I added a screen shot of the one that looks the most obvious. I also made several attempts in code with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out. In the function supportedInterfaceOrientations in CCDirectorIOS.m I always return the value UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft.